# My Width page its larger than my Browser

Tags: html, css, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am a novice in these languages ​​and I still have some difficulty assimilating things , as for me I will facilitate changing code examples I find on the internet.

Right now I'm with two difficulties in my project .

1 I have a small blank I can not see where it is in code.

2 The width of the generated page is larger then of the browser page .

My code

```css
/************************************************************************
*                                                                       *
*                  Sinorcaish Screen-based Style Sheet                  *
*                 Copyright (C) 2004-07, John Zaitseff                  *
*                                                                       *
************************************************************************/

/* Author:  John Zaitseff <J.Zaitseff@zap.org.au>
   Version: 1.3

   $Id: sinorcaish-screen.css 189 2007-03-22 01:35:44Z john $

   This file provides the Sinorcaish style sheet for screen-based user
   agents (ie, for ordinary Web browsers).  This file conforms to the
   Cascading Style Sheets 2.1 specification.

   The design of Sinorcaish is influenced by Sinorca (available from the
   Open Source Web Design site, http://www.oswd.org/), which in turn was
   based on the Acronis company web site (http://www.acronis.com/).  You
   can find more information about this design from its home page on the
   ZAP Group web site, http://www.zap.org.au/documents/styles/sinorcaish/.

   This file may be redistributed and/or modified on the condition that
   the original copyright notice is retained.
*/


/********** Global Styles **********/

    /* The global font size is set to 90% as  */
    /* most browsers' normal font size is too */
    /* large, at least when using Verdana     */
html,body {
   font-family:     Verdana, "DejaVu Sans", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Lucida Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size:       90%; /* Allow IE/Win to resize the document */
   color:           black;
   background:      white;
   margin:          0;
   padding:         0;
   border:          none;
   w
}

.hidden {   /* Used for content that should be displayed */
    /* by non-stylesheet-aware browsers          */
   display:         none !important;
}

.notprinted {   /* Used for content that should not be */
}    /* printed to paper                    */


/* Headings */

h1,    /* Headings (H1-H6) should only be used in */
h2,    /* the main content area                   */
h3 {
   font-weight:     bold;
   text-align:      left;
   margin:          0.5em 0 0 0;
   padding:         0;
}

h4,
h5,
h6 {
   font-weight:     bold;
   text-align:      left;
   margin:          1.25em 0 0 0;
   padding:         0;
}

h1 { font-size:     175% }
h2 { font-size:     145% }
h3 { font-size:     120% }
h4 { font-size:     105% }
h5 { font-size:     80%  }
h6 { font-size:     65%  }


/* Anchors */

a:link {
   text-decoration: none;
   color:           #0066CC;
   background:      transparent;
}

a:visited {
   text-decoration: none;
   color:           #003399;
   background:      transparent;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
   text-decoration: underline;
}


/* Inline elements and classes */

    /* This style sheet assumes B, BIG, EM, I, */
    /* SMALL, STRONG, SUB and SUP are defined  */
    /* by the browser as per the HTML4 sample  */
    /* style sheet.                            */
code,
kbd,
samp,
tt {
   font-family:     "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
   font-size:       115%; /* Courier tends to be a little too small */
   line-height:     1.0; /* Otherwise lines tend to spread out */
}

kbd,
code.markup,   /* HTML/CSS markup */
span.markup,   /* Alternative form for HTML/CSS markup */
.title {   /* Title in floating boxes / left sidebar */
   font-weight:     bolder;
}

abbr,
acronym {
   font:            inherit; /* Don't use small-caps, etc. */
}

.tooltip {
   cursor:          help;
   border-bottom:   1px dotted #CCCCCC;
}

abbr[title],
acronym[title] {
   cursor:          help;
   border-bottom:   1px dotted #CCCCCC;
}

cite,
dfn,
var,
.fn,    /* Filename */
.url,    /* Uniform Resource Locator */
.email {   /* E-mail address */
   font-style:      italic;
}

.program,   /* Command-line name of a computer program */
.window,   /* Window or dialog box name */
.menu,    /* Menu item in a computer program */
.gui,    /* Generic GUI element in a computer program */
.key {    /* Keypress in a computer program */
   font-weight:     bolder;
}

.clearboxes {   /* Clear navboxes and floatboxes */
   clear:           right;
}

.unicode {
   font-family:     "Arial Unicode MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, "DejaVu Sans", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Lucida Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/* Block-inline elements and classes */

img {
   vertical-align:  baseline;
   margin:          0;
   padding:         0;
   border:          none;
}

img.icon16 {   /* For 16x16 file-type icons */
   vertical-align:  -2px;
}

del,
del * {    /* Required for Mozilla */
   text-decoration: line-through;
}

ins,
ins * {    /* Required for Mozilla */
   text-decoration: underline;
}

.floatleft {   /* Left-floating images and spans */
   margin:          0.5em 1.5em 0.5em 0;
   float:           left;
}

.floatright {   /* Right-floating images and spans */
   margin:          0.5em 0 0.5em 1.5em;
   float:           right;
}

.nowrap {
   white-space:     nowrap;
}


/* Block elements */

p {
   margin:          1em 0;
   padding:         0;
}

blockquote {   /* Should only be used in main content area, */
    /* floating boxes or left sidebar.           */
   margin:          1em 2.5em;
   padding:         0;
}

pre {    /* Should only be used in main content area  */
    /* and floating boxes.                       */
   font-family:     "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
   font-size:       95%; /* Courier tends to be a little too small */
   line-height:     1.2;
   margin:          1em 2.5em;
   padding:         0;
}

pre code,
pre kbd,
pre samp,
pre tt {
   font-size:       100%; /* PRE is already enlarged above */
   line-height:     1.2; /* Use same value as for PRE above */
}

hr {
   color:           #999999;
   background:      transparent;
   height:          1px; /* Required for IE/Win */
   margin:          0;
   padding:         0;
   border-color:    #999999;
   border-width:    1px;
   border-style:    none none solid none;
}

hr.lighter {   /* Warning: not printed out on paper */
   color:           #F0F0F0;
   background:      transparent;
   border-color:    #F0F0F0;
}


/* Lists */

ol {
   list-style:      decimal outside;
   margin:          1em 0;
   padding:         0 0 0 2.5em;
}

ol.alpha {
   list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}

ol.number {
   list-style-type: decimal;
}

ul {
   list-style:      square outside;
   margin:          1em 0;
   padding:         0 0 0 2.5em;
}

ol ol,
ol ul,
ul ol,
ul ul {
   margin-top:      0;
   margin-bottom:   0;
}

ol ul,    /* Override possible browser styles */
ol ol ul,
ol ul ul,
ul ul,
ul ol ul,
ul ul ul {
   list-style:      square outside;
}

li {
   margin:          0;
   padding:         0;
}

dl {
   margin:          1em 0;
   padding:         0;
}

dt {
   font:            inherit; /* Don't make the text bold by default */
   margin:          1em 0 0.25em 0;
   padding:         0;
}

dd {
   margin:          0 0 1em 2.5em;
   padding:         0;
}


/* Tables */
    /* Tables should never be used for visual */
    /* formatting: that is the role of CSS!   */

table.simple {
   color:           inherit;
   background:      inherit; /* Don't make tables transparent */
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border-spacing:  0;
   empty-cells:     show;
   margin:          0.5em 2.5em;
   padding:         0;
   border:          1px solid #999999;
}

table.simple caption {
   text-align:      center;
   caption-side:    top;
   margin:          0 2.5em 0.75em;
   padding:         0;
   border:          none;
}

table.simple td,
table.simple th {
   text-align:      center;
   vertical-align:  middle;
   margin:          0;
   padding:         0.25em 0.5em;
   border:          1px solid #999999;
}

table.simple th,
table.simple td.highlight,
table.simple th.highlight {
   font-weight:     bold;
   color:           inherit;
   background:      #F0F0F0;
}

table.simple td.lighter,
table.simple th.lighter {
   color:           inherit;
   background:      #F8F8F8;
}

table.simple td.left,
table.simple th.left {
   text-align:      left;
}

table.simple td.center,
table.simple th.center {
   text-align:      center;
}

table.simple td.right,
table.simple th.right {
   text-align:      right;
}


/* Forms */

form {
   margin:          1em 0;
   padding:         0;
   border:          none;
}

input,
button,
select,
fieldset,
legend {
   font-family:     Verdana, "DejaVu Sans", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Lucida Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size:       95%;
   color:           black;
   background:      inherit;
   vertical-align:  middle;
}

textarea {
   font-family:     "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
   font-size:       100%;
   color:           black;
   background:      inherit;
   vertical-align:  middle;
}

fieldset {
   font-size:       100%;
   margin:          1em 0;
   border:          1px solid #999999;
}

legend {
   font-size:       100%;
   margin:          0 0.5em;
   padding:         0 0.25em;
   border:          none;
}

table.formtable {
   color:           inherit;
   background:      inherit;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border-spacing:  0;
   empty-cells:     show;
   margin:          0;
   padding:         0;
   border:          none;
}

table.formtable td,
table.formtable th {
   text-align:      justify;
   vertical-align:  middle;
   margin:          0;
   padding:         0.25em 0.5em;
   border:          none;
}

table.formtable th {
   text-align:      center;
   font-weight:     bold;
}

table.formtable td.label,
table.formtable th.label {
   text-align:      right;
   vertical-align:  top;
}

table.formtable td.vertspace,
table.formtable th.vertspace {
   empty-cells:     show;
   margin:          0;
   padding:         0.5em 0;
   height:          1em; /* Required for IE/Win */
}

table.formtable fieldset {
   margin:          0;
}

table.formtable fieldset td,
table.formtable fieldset th {
   margin:          0.25em 0.5em;
}

.reqfield {
   color:           red;
   background:      transparent;
   font-weight:     bolder;
}

.info {
   color:           gray;
   background:      transparent;
   font-size:       90%;
}


/* The following HTML elements should NOT be used in documents using this
   style sheet:

       address - use the #footer style instead
       q       - use &ldquo; and &rdquo; instead
*/


/********** Styles for Main Content **********/

#main {
   text-align:      justify;
   line-height:     1.5;
   color:           black;
   background:      white;
   margin:          0 0 0 12.5em;
   padding:         0.1em 1.5em 0.5em 1em;
   border-left:     1px solid #999999;
    width: 100%;
}

#main h1 {   /* Should be used once, following navhead */
   color:           #999999;
   background:      transparent;
   margin:          0 0 0.5em 0;
}

#main .highlight {  /* Highlight box (for warnings, etc) */
   color:           inherit;
   background:      #F0F0F0;
   margin:          1em 0;
   padding:         1em 2.5em;
   border:          1px solid #999999;
}

#main .totop {   /* For "Top ^" lines in FAQs, etc */
   font-size:       90%;
   text-align:      right;
   margin:          -0.75em 0 1em 0;
   padding:         0 0 0.25em 0;
   border-bottom:   1px solid #F0F0F0;
}

#main table.simple td.highlight,  /* Else "#main .highlight" will override */
#main table.simple th.highlight {
   margin:          0;
   padding:         0.25em 0.5em;
}


/* Other styles related to the main content */

#mainlink {   /* "Skip to main content" link */
   display:         none !important;
}

#navhead {   /* "Path to this page" information */
    /* Warning: not printed out on paper */
   font-size:       90%;
}

#navhead hr {
   display:         none;
}

#endmain {
   visibility:      hidden;
   clear:           both; /* Doesn't always work under IE/Win */
}


/********** Styles for Floating Boxes **********/

    /* "navbox" is used to provide intra/inter- */
    /* page links; it is NOT printed out on     */
    /* paper.  "floatbox" is used to provide    */
    /* floating boxes that may appear anywhere  */
    /* in the main content; they ARE printed.   */
.floatbox,
.navbox {
   overflow:        visible;
   font-size:       95%;
   line-height:     1.25;
   margin:          0 0 0.75em 1.5em;
   padding:         0.5em 1em;
   border:          1px solid #999999;
   float:           right;
   clear:           right;
}

.floatbox {
   color:           black;
   background:      #F0F0F0;
   width:           35%;
}

.navbox {
   text-align:      left;
   color:           black;
   background:      white;
   width:           12.5em;
}

.floatbox hr,   /* Used for non-stylesheet-aware browsers */
.navbox hr {
   display:         none !important;
}

.floatbox p,
.navbox p {
   margin:          0.75em 0;
   padding:         0;
}

.floatbox ol,
.floatbox ul {
   margin:          0.75em 0;
   padding:         0 0 0 1.5em;
}

.navbox ol,
.navbox ul {
   margin:          0.5em 0;
   padding:         0 0 0 1.5em;
}

.floatbox blockquote {
   margin:          0.75em 1.5em;
   padding:         0;
}

.floatbox pre {
   font-size:       95%;
   margin:          0.75em 1.5em;
   padding:         0;
}

.floatbox dt {
   margin:          0.75em 0;
   padding:         0;
}

.floatbox dt {
   margin:          0.75em 0 0.25em 0;
   padding:         0;
}

.floatbox dd {
   margin:          0 0 0.75em 1.5em;
   padding:         0;
}

#main .floatbox .highlight {
   color:           inherit;
   background:      white;
   margin:          0.75em 0;
   padding:         0.75em 1.5em;
}

#main .floatbox table.simple {
   margin:          0.75em 0;
}

#main .floatbox table.simple th,
#main .floatbox table.simple td.highlight,
#main .floatbox table.simple th.highlight {
   color:           inherit;
   background:      white;
   margin:          0;
   padding:         0.25em 0.5em;
}


/********** Styles for Header **********/

    /* In this style sheet, headers are composed */
    /* of three parts: left, right and subheader */
    /* Left part is ideally an image.            */

#header {   /* Warning: not printed out on paper */
   color:           #003399;
  /* background:      #8CA8E6; */
  padding: 0.5px 1px; color: #fff; background: #6c90df url('../Css/bar_head.png') repeat-x 100% top; 
   /*background-image: "CSS/grd_head.png"*/
   width: 100%;
}

#header a:link,
#header a:visited {
   color:           #003399;
   background:      transparent;
}

#header .highlight,
#header a.highlight:link,
#header a.highlight:visited {
   color:           white;
   background:      transparent;
}

/* Left part of header (ideally an image but may be a link) */

#header div.left {
   float:           left;
   clear:           left;
   margin:          0;
   padding:         0;
}

#header div.left img {
   display:         block; /* Otherwise IMG is an inline, causing gaps */
}

#header div.left,
#header div.left a:link,
#header div.left a:visited {
   font-size:       200%;
   font-weight:     bold;
   text-decoration: none;
   color:           white;
   background:      transparent;
   
}

#header div.left p {
   margin:          0 0 0 0.25em;
   padding:         0;
}

#header div.left .alt {
   color:           #FF9800;
   background:      transparent;
}

/* Right part of header is for external/global links, search, etc */

#header div.right {
   font-size:       90%;
   text-align:      right;
   margin:          0;
   padding:         0.5em 1.17em 0 1em;
   float:           right;
   clear:           right;
}

#header div.right a:link,
#header div.right a:visited {
   margin:          0;
   padding:         0 0.5em;
}

#header div.right form {
   margin:          0;
   padding:         0.25em 0.5em 0 0;
}

#header div.right form input {
   font-size:       95%;
   vertical-align:  middle;
}

/* Subheader for global links */

#header div.subheader {
   color:           white;
   background:      #003399;
   margin:          0;
   padding:         0;
   border:          1px solid #003399; /* Required for IE/Win */
   clear:           both;
}

#header div.subheader p { /* To overcome an IE/Win unwanted padding */
    /* bug, still present in IE7.             */
   margin:          0;
   padding:         0.5em;
}

#header div.subheader a:link,
#header div.subheader a:visited {
   font-weight:     bolder;
   color:           white;
   background:      transparent;
   margin:          0;
   padding:         0 0.5em;
}

#header div.subheader .highlight,
#header div.subheader a.highlight:link,
#header div.subheader a.highlight:visited {
   color:           #FDA05E;
   background:      transparent;
}


/********** Styles for Left Sidebar **********/

#sidebar {   /* Warning: not printed out on paper */
   width:           12.5em;
   border-right:    1px solid #999999;
   float:           left;
   background-color:#F0F0F0;
   clear:           both;
}

#sidebar div {
   font-size:       95%;
   margin:          0;
   padding:         0.25em 0.25em;
}

#sidebar div.lighter {
   color:           inherit;
   background:      white;
}

#sidebar p {
   margin:          0.5em 0;
}

#sidebar .title a:link,
#sidebar .title a:visited {
   color:           black;
   background:      transparent;
}

#sidebar ul {
   list-style:      none outside;
   margin:          0.5em 0;
   padding:         0;
}

#sidebar ul li {
   margin:          0;
   padding:         0.125em 0;
}

#sidebar ul li.highlight {
   color:           inherit;
   background:      white;
   margin-left:     -1em;
   margin-right:    -1em;
   padding-left:    1em;
   border-top:      1px solid #999999;
   border-bottom:   1px solid #999999;
}

#sidebar ul li.highlight a:link,
#sidebar ul li.highlight a:visited {
   color:           black;
   background:      transparent;
}


/********** Styles for Footer **********/

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}


#footer {
   font-size:       90%;
   text-align:      left;
   color:           white;
   /*background:      #6381DC; */
      color:           #003399;
  /* background:      #8CA8E6; */
  padding: 4px 2px; color: #fff; background: #6c90df url('../Css/bar_head.png') repeat-x 10% top; 
   margin:          0;
   padding:         0.5em 1.67em 0.5em 15.25em;
   clear:           both;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
}


#footer a:link,
#footer a:visited {
   text-decoration: underline;
   color:           white;
   background:      transparent;
}

#footer hr {
   display:         none !important;
}

/* End of the Sinorcaish style sheet */
```

```html
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="Home.master.vb" Inherits="Home" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server" >
    <title> </title>
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link href="CSS/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/sinorcaish-screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/CustomStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body class="body" >
    <form id="form1" runat="server" class="body" >
        <!-- ======== Header ======== -->
        <div id="header">
          <div class="left">
              teste
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            <%=DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()%>
              <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="25px" 
                  ImageUrl="~/Images/sair_64.png" Width="25px" />
          </div>
          <div class="subheader">
            <em></em>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- ======== Left Sidebar ======== -->
        <div id="sidebar">
          <div>
            <ul>
               
                <p>Importações</p>
                <li><a href="Paginas/ImportStock.aspx">Importar Stock Médico</a></li>
                <li><a href="Paginas/ImportStock.aspx">Importar Stock Enfermeiros</a></li>


                 </ul>

                 <ul>
               <li> </li>
               <li> </li>
               <li> </li>
                <p>Configuração Tabelas</p>
                <li><a href="Paginas/consulta_gruposprof.aspx">Grupos Profissionais</a></li>
                <li><a href="Paginas/grupoprof_gere.aspx">Regiões</a></li>
                </ul>
           
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- ======== Main Content ======== -->
        <div id="main" class="body">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" >
          
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        
        <!-- ======== Footer ======== -->

        <div id="footer">
            h
            Website design by <a href="http://www.highvalue.pt/">H</a>
            <a href="http://www.highvalue.pt/">H</a>
        </div>
        
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank's!!!

Comment: Can you please reduce this to a minimal example? It's not easy to tell exactly what you are asking.

Comment: You cannot expect anyone to debug a 867 line css file for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're giving the element  **#main**  a width of 100% and also a padding, making the box a total of (100% + total horizontal padding) wide. If you want to add padding to a box without changing it's size add: box-sizing: border-box.

https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: Thank you for the quick response .

I deleted the line of padding and continued in the same way .
I did the same in the remaining elements (if that makes any sense ) , for the case to be one that was to add the width but also failed.

Comment: Hi @Paula, I'm not sure I understand what you're telling me, but it's not the padding you need to worry about, it's perfectly fine as is, the only issue is you haven't told the container element (#main) that it should't grow if you add padding to it.

#main{
box-sizing: border-box;
....

Comment: If you want all elements to act this way by default, many people use the universal selector as such:  *{box-sizing: border-box} (refers to ALL elements)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your css to this:

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

html,body {
   font-family:     Verdana, "DejaVu Sans", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Lucida Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size:       90%;    /* Allow IE/Win to resize the document */
   color:           black;
   background:      white;
   border:          none;
   width:           100%;
   height:          100%;
}
```

Some browsers (like Google Chrome) have predefined margins and paddings. The * symbol selects everything in the document, by using * you get rid of those pesky predefined margins and paddings.

Furthermore I've changed the width and height of the body and html tags to stretch to 100% of the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="width:99%;">
    <!-- ======== Header ======== -->
    <div id="header">
      <div class="left">
          teste
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <%=DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()%>
          <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="25px" 
              ImageUrl="~/Images/sair_64.png" Width="25px" />
      </div>
      <div class="subheader">
        <em></em>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ======== Left Sidebar ======== -->
    <div id="sidebar">
      <div>
        <ul>

            <p>Importações</p>
            <li><a href="Paginas/ImportStock.aspx">Importar Stock Médico</a></li>
            <li><a href="Paginas/ImportStock.aspx">Importar Stock Enfermeiros</a></li>


             </ul>

             <ul>
           <li> </li>
           <li> </li>
           <li> </li>
            <p>Configuração Tabelas</p>
            <li><a href="Paginas/consulta_gruposprof.aspx">Grupos Profissionais</a></li>
            <li><a href="Paginas/grupoprof_gere.aspx">Regiões</a></li>
            </ul>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ======== Main Content ======== -->
    <div id="main" class="body">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" >

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>

    <!-- ======== Footer ======== -->

    <div id="footer">
        h
        Website design by <a href="http://www.highvalue.pt/">H</a>
        <a href="http://www.highvalue.pt/">H</a>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Change the code from  to  with this. Hope it helps

Comment: -1 ... what You think how look like with 99%?? Imagine that 1% on screen with res., talking about width, 800px and screen with 1280, 1600px ... look @leuquim answer. downvote.

Answer (score 0):

This due to the padding in #main

```
#main{    
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0 0 0 12.5em;
 /*   padding: 0.1em 1.5em 0.5em 1em;*/
    text-align: justify;
    width: 100%;
}
```

remove the padding in #main and it should work.